# Keeping columns of pandas dataframe whose substring is in the list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with many columns. I only want to retain those columns whose substring is in the list. For example the lst and dataframe is:

```
lst = ['col93','col71']

sample_id.    col9381.3     col8371.8      col71937.9      col19993.1
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

Based on the substrings, the resulting dataframe will look like:

```
sample_id.    col9381.3   col71937.9  
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

I have a code that go through the list and filter out the columns for whom I have a substring in a list but I don't know how to create a dataframe for it. The code so far:

```
for i in lst:
    df2 = df1.filter(regex=i)
    if df2.shape[1] > 0:
        print(df2)
```

The above code is able to filter out the columns but I don't know how combine all of these into one dataframe. Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `startswith` which accepts a tuple of options:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('sample_id.',)+tuple(lst))]
```

Or `filter` which accepts a regex as you were trying:

```
df.filter(regex='|'.join(['sample_id']+lst))
```

Output:

```
   sample_id.  col9381.3  col71937.9
0           1        NaN         NaN
1           2        NaN         NaN
2           3        NaN         NaN
3           4        NaN         NaN
```